# Dynamic JSON Data Object in GSON

Tags: java, android, json, api, gson

I'm having a bit of trouble with GSON reading my API response JSON.

My API data returns an object with a status code, message and a data object.

The problem that I have with GSON, is that I can't figure out how to work with it properly.

For example, my API response can look like this.

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "message": "",
    "data": {
        "auth_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "points": 42850
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "message": "",
    "data": {
        "items": [
          {
            "title" : "value"
          },
          {
            "title" : "value"
          }
        ]
    }
}
```

**OR others**

The first response, which is a login response would be a class LoginResponse.class

```
public class LoginResponse {

    private String auth_token;
    private int points;

    public String getAuthToken(){
        return auth_token;
    }

    public int getPoints(){
        return points;
    }

}
```

and I'd use

```
LoginResponse response = gson.fromJson(json, LoginResponse.class);
```

But, how can I create a class so I can access the status code, message and the data? (which could be any of the response classes that I have)

I've looked at TypeAdapterFactory and JsonDeserializer, but couldn't get my head around it.

So, if anyone can find a SO answer that answers this question, that'd be great because I couldn't find one, or if you know how to do just this.

Answer (score 1):

You could have code and message as normal, and then `data` could be a `Map<String, Object>` that you would have to interpret at runtime depending on the code or whatever you use to differentiate how the response should look.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by doing this:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject rootObejct = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
JsonElement dataElement = rootObejct.get("data");
LoginResponse response = gson.fromJson(dataElement, LoginResponse.class);
```